# Calculating the time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

Can somebody help with the time complexity of the following code:

```
for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
   for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
      {
         for(k = 2; k <= n; k = k^2)
              print("")
      }
```

a/c to me the first loop will run n times,2nd will run for(1+2+3...n) times and third for loglogn times..
but i m not sure about the answer.

Comment: SO is not for homework assignments. Please post what have you tried

Comment: done...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start from the inside and work out. Consider the innermost loop:

```
for(k = 2; k <= n; k = k^2)
    print("")
```

How many iterations of `print("")` are executed? First note that `n` is constant. What sequence of values does `k` assume?

```
iter | k
--------
   1 | 2
   2 | 4
   3 | 16
   4 | 256
```

We might find a formula for this in several ways. I used guess and prove to get `iter = log(log(k)) + 1`. Since the loop won't execute the next iteration if the value is already bigger than `n`, the total number of iterations executed for `n` is `floor(log(log(n)) + 1)`. We can check this with a couple of values to make sure we got this right. For `n = 2`, we get one iteration which is correct. For `n = 5`, we get two. And so on.

The next level does `i + 1` iterations, where `i` varies from 0 to `n`. We must therefore compute the sum `1, 2, ..., n + 1` and that will give us the total number of iterations of the outermost and middle loop: this sum is `(n + 1)(n + 2) / 2` We must multiply this by the cost of the inner loop to get the answer, `(n + 1)(n + 2)(log(log(n)) + 1) / 2` to get the total cost of the snippet. The fastest-growing term in the expansion is `n^2 log(log(n))` and so that is what would typically be given as asymptotic complexity.